# Check class of a resource in Jena

Tags: java, jena, owl, ontology, rdfs

To check if a resource is a class etc I can do like this:

```
OntModel onto = onto.getOntology();

if (onto.getOntResource(s).isClass())
    OntClass c = onto.getOntResource(s).asClass();

if (onto.getOntResource(s).isProperty()) {
            OntProperty prop = onto.getOntResource(s).asProperty(); 

if (onto.getOntResource(s).isIndividual())
```

But if I create a inference model from the same ontology as follows:

```
InfModel InfOnto = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, onto1.getOntology());
```

How to do the class, property and individual checking as above?

For example InfOnto has no method to check if a resource is a Class and also to convert a resource to a Class

Comment: What doesn't work about the code you showed when you're using an InfModel?

Comment: I have edited the question, please see if it makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: Just from the docs, `OntModel` is an extension of `InfModel`. And you should wrap the `InfModel` into the `OntModel`, see the explanation at https://jena.apache.org/documentation/javadoc/jena/org/apache/jena/ontology/OntModel.html .

Comment: I tried something like: InfModel infOntoModel = ModelFactory.createInfModel(reasoner, onto1.getOntology());OntModel onto = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, infOntoModel); is it what you mean by wrapping?

Comment: @eagleye I didn't write the other comment, but yes, I think that's what AKSW is talking about.  Did that work for you?  The idea of `createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec,Model base)` is to create an OntModel that realizes certain ontology language constructs (e.g., OntClass == instance of owl:Class) and puts/gets its triples from the base model.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I think yes, it's working me.